# negating "unknown" value in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm currently learning SQL Server by studying the book "T-SQL Fundamentals Third Edition". In the book, there is the following quote:

> One tricky aspect of the logical value “unknown” is that when you
>   negate it, you still get “unknown”. For example, given the predicate
>   “not (salary > 0)”, when salary is “null”, “salary > 0” evaluates to
>   “unknown”, and “not known” remain “unknown”

I'm a bit confused by all the logic behind the statement, just wondering if anyone would clarify things a little bit?

Would someone also add a code example?

Comment: Just create a test table with some positive, negative and NULL values. Then run `SELECT ... WHERE v > 0` and `SELECT ... WHERE NOT(v > 0)`. You'll see how it works. In both variants your NULL values will **not** be selected.

Comment: That's a very, VERY poorly phrased example. If "salary > 0" evaluates to "unknown", then "not unknown" would be "known"...

Comment: @VladimirBaranov your comment helped me understand the concept! thank you so much!

Comment: @zlk it's also not what the book actually says. https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2225058&seqNum=4

Answer (score 2):

Let's try to explain.  `NULL` means an "unknown" value (although in practice, it usually represents a *missing* value).

When you have an expression such as "salary > 0", the interpretation is "unknown value" > 0".  Is this true or false?  Wrong!  This is "unknown".

Almost all logical operators produce "unknown" when one or more of the operands are "unknown".  When processing a query, "unknown" is treated as not-True, so it is functionally equivalent to false in a `where` or `when` condition.

Similarly, `NOT "unknown value"` evaluates to . . . "unknown".

Two important exceptions to this rule are `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`.  The first evaluates to true and the second to false.

Some databases offer `NULL-safe` comparisons (for instance, Postgres offers `IS DISTINCT FROM`), which treat `NULL = NULL` as true.  SQL Server does not offer such an explicit operator.  `NULL-safe` operators can be handy when you have logic that wants to check for `NULL`s and you would also like the optimizer to use an index.

Answer (score 1):

from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204037.aspx

NULL indicates that the value is unknown. A null value is different from an empty or zero value. No two null values are equal. Comparisons between two null values, or between a null value and any other value, return unknown because the value of each NULL is unknown.

to work properly with NULL values, use "IS NULL", you cant comparise a NULL value with anything because it will always satisfy the contidition (i.e. (NULL value < 0) is true, and (NULL value > 0) is true)

Answer (score 0):

"Unknown" is a result of two operands. And the operand can be a NULL.

Simple terms

**A NULL is operand.**

**Unknown is not operand**

**Unknown can be result of two operands**

Please refer below link. There are few tables which will give mire detailed difference.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204037.aspx